# Android studio stuck at Refreshing Gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio

Updated Android studio to 1.2.2 and the background process wont end.(Refreshing 'MemoryCards' Gradle project).

It has been more than an hour now and its still busy?

[image]

Is this normal and why is it taking this long? its a small app.

Here is my idea.log : https://www.dropbox.com/s/syf12m3lxbww5k7/idea.log?dl=0

Update:

Disabled my proxy settings in android studio and the refreshing process continued and showed me the following.
[image]

It failed at the download of the gradle zip :

[image]

So the reason I think that It takes this long it was trying to download the gradle zip file +- 60 Mb and my internet connection is slow...

So the process continues when I disable the proxy settings but then it cant download the gradle zip file... ? so it fails again.

Update :

I used another Internet source and it downloaded the gradle and the process continued.

Comment: Whatever the cause, hanging for an hour is not "normal". I suggest you make a bug report.

Comment: I am downloading the gradle-2.2.1-all.zip file in my browser.. Where should I unzip the contents?

Comment: I just faced this issue 3 hours back on updating from Android Studio 2 Preview 7 to 8. I left it for 2 hours and watched The Martian. 2 hours into the movie, towards the end, I get a gradle notification saying it’s complete. Issue fixed!

Comment: What if I don't have The Martian?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A few things to try in the following order:

1. Restart the entire PC, then try again...
2. If that fails then clear the cache for android studio, restart
   android studio and try again..
3. Disable any proxies on your PC / network / Android studio then try again

If that doesn't work then look at clearing the gradle files and re-downloading them. Let me know how this goes please and I can update my answer with further things to do if needed.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, How do you clear the cache for android studio?

Comment: I believe there is a "invalidate caches / restart" in Menu File.

Comment: @apmartin1991 I did restart my pc but no effect. So the process continues when I disable the proxy settings but then it cant download the gradle zip file... ? so it fails again. Please see my updated post.

Comment: I used another Internet source and it downloaded the gradle and the process continued. Thanks for you help.

Comment: No worries, if the answer was correct then please mark it as correct, if you needed to do something else then please answer your own question and then mark it as correct so that future people will know what fixed it for you :)

Comment: In my case all options in file menu are disabled, even unable to close current project, any suggestion guys? Thanks

Comment: It isn't the answer. simply it was wrong path in the file->settings->tools->gardle .. just remove the path then apply

Answer (score 29):

In Android Studio select: 
**File\Settings\Build, Execution, Deployment\Build tools\Gradle**
click on the button on the right side showing local gradle distribution path.
 you will be taken to the gradle folder.
 click ok in this dialog box and your path will be updated!

restart android studio and you are good to go!

**The Problem:**
in my case path selected after the update was of older version e.g:
**C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.4**
However, after the update it was changed to:
**C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-2.8**

**P.S:**
This solution also resolves following error: 
**buildTypes cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure**

Comment: 1 for mentioning the cause

Comment: Just had this issue when upgrading from Android Studio 2.2.3 to 2.3. This was the solution.

Comment: Thanks it works for gradle stuck after upgrading Android Studio 2.3

Answer (score 7):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27784297/1157720) answer suggests, **Removing .gradle directory from home** helps solving this problem in some cases.

Comment: I updated gradle path in settings and it didn't work. Your answer worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Change gradle home directory to exist location.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I run into  this problem on Windows 7 after an update of the Android studio and this works for me:

**Run the Android Studio with Administrative Privileges.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I just updated my android studio to 2.0 on ubuntu 14.04. This issue arose for one of the project and it was solved through a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752520/1713531) here which seems unrelated to this problem !!

If you are using Android Studio 2.0 Beta, this issue might appear (more likely if you are working on NTFS filesystem) and it seems like the "Instant Run" is the culprit. Search for "Instant Run" in settings and uncheck the box

Posting here to an old question - maybe somebody else might me  stuck on this aswell.

Answer (score 2):

**These steps work for me :**

1. Close android studio first
2. Go to folder C:\Users\.gradle and delete that folder.
3. Then in gradle folder create gradle.properties file and add
       following lines.

> ```
>  org.gradle.daemon=true
>  org.gradle.parallel=true
> ```

4. Open android studio

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me quite a few times and there is no single solution.You should try some of the solutions mentioned below.

1. `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
2. **Update** Android studio and Gradle to the latest version
3. Select the correct Gradle distribution by going to `Settings/Preferences -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Gradle` and select the path for *local Gradle distribution*
4. Restart your computer

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal try :

```
gradlew clean
```

Then invalidate caches and its works...
It will redownload all libraries from internet and build successfully
You can also delete build,.gradle,gradle folders to force re-cleaning

Answer (score 1):

Turning off my VPN solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse to Android Studio 1.4, then the project works.....

And when I update it to 1.5, the project start stucking with refreshing >_<

Might not help, but worth a try~

Comment: this is not a proper solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

Answer of [Lloric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966316/4504277) is the perfect answer.

Go to `Settings > Build Tools > Gradle`

Then change the `Gradle Home` path to the existing path.

Probably you are facing problem now with `gradle-2.10`

Browse directory, you will find out `gradle-2.14.1` as of mine or later versions.

Change it to that then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I download Gradle zip from the web site, and set the gradle local home, enabled offline work. Then "file" menu -> restart. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

if gradle has downloaded correctly and you just have problem with this project, follow these steps:

1. Delete **.gradle** folder from your project's root.
2. File > Invalidate Caches/restart.

[image: Stucking gradle in adnroid studio]

**Note**: if android studio didn't restarted, kill it's process in Task Manager.

Some other solutions:

- Adding android studio to Firewall and Antivirus exceptions (or turn off both temporary)
- Adding **mavenCentral()** to project build.gradle after **jcenter()** line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading existing project into new Android studio then it's gradle library version that you have specified in your top level build.gradle file.
Check version and move to latest or compatible version for android studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a wrong path in the file->settings->tools->gardle .. just remove the path then apply.

Then restart android studio (you may need to end task)

Answer (score -2):

If you get a connection timed out error this is usually a problem of proxies. Try disabling them if you are using proxies.

Also, when gradle is stuck, deleting the `.gradle` folder in `c:\Users\` always helped me.

Comment: I should have read the other answers before editing. This answer does not really contribute anything new.  All of this is covered in the accepted answer .