# Android Studio Stuck at opening Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated from Android Studio 2.0 to 2.1.2 and now I have a project which doesn't open. Android Studio is stuck at the following screen for more than 10-15min. 
[image]

I tried solutions from these answers.[[ans1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873/android-studio-stuck-at-gradle-download-on-create-new-project) [[ans2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799712/android-studio-stuck-at-refreshing-gradle-project)
but none of them work.

I can create new projects and also import projects built on eclipse. But cannot open my own project.

Please help.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this?

Answer (score 7):

Delete the gradle folder in the project folder. It will work.

Comment: Do not forget to take a backup

Comment: This solution works. but I had to wait again for downloading the graddle files.

Comment: Which gradle folder? I hace the following resources in the root of my project folder:

.gradle\
gradle\
gradlew
gradlew.bat
gradle.properties

Should I delete all of them?

Answer (score 1):

For many problems such as stuck with opening or downloading something while starting
I use this sequence as an ultimate guide and on one of the steps always works out.
Recently I used it after updating to 3.2

1. Try File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Start Android Studio (Studio will download gradle data)
5. After Gradle build is done, rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Studio's Known Issues https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues under "Configuration on demand with Gradle 4.6 and above:", if you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.x or 3.1.x with Gradle 4.6 and above you should add the following line to gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand = false
```

This seemed to solve my issue with Android Studio getting stuck at "Project setup: reading from cache".