# Some gradle issue after updating Android Studio to v2.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I have updated Android Studio, and when opening a project done in the 1.5 version this is the error I am getting:

> Error:Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be
>   corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>   network)

The following is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Gradle sync error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770909/android-studio-gradle-sync-error)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I updated my android studio to 2.2.3 from 2.1.
After a while of struggling, went project->right click -> open module settings->project

1) Gradle : 2.14.1
2) Android plugin version : 2.2.3
3) Android plugin repository : jcenter
4) Default library repository : jcenter

Comment: facing this same issue but those values are my default