# Android Studio 2.3 Error:Unable to load class 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet'

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

Everybody!

Suddenly, when I opened my exists project I'd got error:

> Error:Unable to load class 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I have not third-party plugin and library otherwise standard.

I tried redownload dependencies, rerun Gradle, reinstall Android Studio 2.3 and Android SDK (downloaded last version), but I've got the same message in my project on in each new simple project in Android Studio.

[Screenshot of new simple project in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soLIl.jpg)

I have Windows 10 with last update.

Please, help!

Comment: I've tried to delete $user\.gradle\cache, restart, clear project and etc...

Comment: Thanks to all! I deleted the .gradle directories in my home directory, so it solved my problem. I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770909/android-studio-gradle-sync-error?rq=1.