# Android Studio: Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions', Gradle Sync Failed

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

When i try opening my projects on Android Studio 3.1.2, I get this Gradle Project Sync failed error with the message below

> Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions'. Possible
>   causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency
>     cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>     timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>     network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be
>     corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop
>     Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be
>     using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
>     plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

## gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

## build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123268/android-studio-2-3-errorunable-to-load-class-com-google-common-collect-immutab before posting duplicate?

Answer (score 6):

The problem has been solved.

I deleted the .gradle folder in my home user directory which made Android Studio re-download all the files for the current version of gradle. It took quite a while to download and sync the first time but it has solved the problem.

Thank you very much for your assistance @Luis Henriques

Comment: Worked for me as well. Was searching for an answer for forever.

Comment: Yup worked for me also.. This should definitely be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project;

Check if you are working on offline mode:

File > Settings > Search for "offline" > uncheck "offline work"

After unchecking offline work, clean and rebuild again.

If it doesn't work, my guess is exactly what it says:

> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not
>   compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of
>   Gradle requested by the project.

Let me know if it worked.

---

UPDATE:

Why do you have:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
...
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Instead of:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
        ...
```

Also use "implementation" instead of "compile". So:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

And why did you set these up in your project.gradle instead of in your app.gradle?

I think your gradle file is poorly structured. Hence the problem. Why don't you see how the default gradle files are set up and compare them with yours?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your local gradle distribution my be corrupt. Delete it and redownload it.