# Android Studio Google Precondition

Tags: java, android, xml, apk

About two weeks ago i started doing some small apps in Android Studio.

Im pretty new to this environment so im having this problem.

Last night i was working on my app, everything was running so i saved and turned off my pc.

Today i opened Android studio and the message:

```
Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions'.
```

And i dont know how to solve it , i already tried this things:

- Do a clean install of Android Studio
- Clean Project & Build project (Tried it but no solution)
- Check "Offline mode" (It was already checked off)
- Invalidate Cache/Restart (Done it but no solution)
- Erase "gradle" folder from my "Android" folder, but no "Automatic" download happened when i reopened so i had to reinstall the application

Ive already saw a lot of posts from differente forums but im not getting any solution

Thanks to all

Comment: `Offline mode` is ***not*** checked, right? Also, see couple of suggested answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288134/android-studio-unable-to-load-class-com-google-common-base-preconditions-gra

Comment: @davedwards hello, ive alried tried everything in that article and yes, offline mode is deactivated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `.gradle` directories both in your home directory and in your project's directory and see if it works. I believe that, since Android Studio will be forced to re-download all the files for the current version of gradle, it might solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with "At the top level of your project"?

Sorry, english is not my native language

Comment: In your project's folder (normally inside the folder `AndroidStudioProjects`), delete all files that have `gradle` in their name. Remember to make a backup before. See if it works and tell us here.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. After i deleted it, Android Studio downloaded all the data and now is working fine

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Please select this as your answer so it can help others as well (click on a grayed out "tick" icon on the left side of the answer).