# I am getting error in android studio "Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Optional'"

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this unexpected error and I tried re-installing the Gradle file still I am facing the same error I even tried rebuilding the project but when I create a new project it gives the same error called **"Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Optional'."**,
**"This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file."**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your .gradle directories from both in home directory and at the top level of tthe project.

Questions  with similar issues
[Android Studio: Unable to load class 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions', Gradle Sync Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288134/android-studio-unable-to-load-class-com-google-common-base-preconditions-gra)